# How can I make it so the user can quickly change to my application

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-mobile-6

This is perhaps an elementary topic; I am almost finished with a small data collection application for windows mobile 6.0.

I want the user to be able to change from using my application to another program(that I did not write) easily, and vice-versa.

I was hoping for some kind of floating button that accesses my application at all times.

Thanks

Comment: There exist many task-switcher add-ons for Windows Mobile, they're mostly a button in the status bar at the top of the screen that shows a bubble with other open/running programs on. Have you tried those?

Comment: hmm, this sounds neat. I want to make sure that these are trustworthy, as they are not my handheld computers. Will they automatically collect open programs, or do they need to be implemented in my code?

Comment: Considering Windows Mobile 6 is six years old and a dead platform, I doubt any of them still "phone home" successfully to a spyware server.

Comment: I am new here; how can I send you good feedback for helping?

Comment: I'll add an answer to the question, just give it an up-vote and click the checkmark. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist many task-switcher add-ons for Windows Mobile, they're mostly a button in the status bar at the top of the screen that shows a bubble with other open/running programs on. Have you tried those?